# Creating a full tag table with HTML

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, deep-learning

I'm actually a beginner in programming and I tried to write a full table codes like ( the pic below), but can anyone write the full taga to me and if I couldn't do it I will try to mimic the right on.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsgXT.jpg)

Comment: Hi @LeGenD A, take a look at this link if you get a moment, people will be much more able to help if they can see any code that you are trying. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple html code. Presented in an understandable way in w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Explanation:
You need first declarate the table, then header and body.

- tr - row
- th - header cell
- td - simple cell

I used a few attributes in tags.

- border - border
- width - table width
- rowspan - An HTML table with a table cell that spans two rows (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)
- colspan - An HTML table with a table cell that spans two columns (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

And I used the following tags:

- img - the image src the url/path alt the text, which appears when you cannot reach the image (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)
- br - break line (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)
- hr - thematic break line (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

The full code:

```html
 <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Avatar</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Character</th>
                <th>Profile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Ninja</td>
                <td><img src="resources/red.jpg" alt="red avatar"></td>
                <td>
                    Osama
                    <br>
                    Mohamed
                </td>
                <td>
                    o1@nn.sa
                    <hr>
                    o2@nn.sa
                </td>
                <td>©</td>
                <td><a href="profile_url">profile</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="resources/blue.jpg" alt="blue avatar"></td>
                <td>
                    Shady
                    <br>
                    Nabil
                </td>
                <td>s@nn.sa</td>
                <td>™</td>
                <td><a href="profile_url">profile</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Monsters</td>
                <td><img src="resources/black.jpg" alt="black avatar"></td>
                <td>
                    Mohamed
                    <br>
                    Ibrahim
                </td>
                <td>m@nn.sa</td>
                <td>®</td>
                <td><a href="profile_url">profile</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Total Members</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```